# Why am I getting an error when converting an array to a string?

Tags: php

```
for($i=0; $i<=count($_FILES['myfile']['name']); $i++)
{
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i],"img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]); //<!-- Error
    $path="img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
}
```

Comment: what error u r getting? pls post

Comment: you can update your question with more error information~

Comment: check `var_dump($_FILES['myfile']`.

Comment: `for($i=0;$i<=count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);$i++)
    {
        if(isset($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i]) && !empty($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i])){
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i],"img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]);
         $path="img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'];
 }
    }
`

Answer (score 1):

I think this line is most likely your problem

```
$path="img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name']
```

Add an index to it like the other references to `$_FILE` in the previous line

```
for($i=0;$i<=count($_FILES['myfile']['name']);$i++) {
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['myfile']['tmp_name'][$i],"img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i]); 
        $path="img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i];   //<- changed line
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your Path into following :

```
$path="img/".$_FILES['myfile']['name'][$i];
```